# How can I get billing information from two tables (bill and customer) for a given meter no?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to know how I can get data from 2 tables where the meter no is same but after a new reading the changed data is displayed on the form after a new reading.

The reading table is that according to bill is generated from...

```
**table name is:bills:**
billno,
meterno,
previousreading,
currentreading,
amount

**second table is customer:**
custid  ,
meterno,
fathername,
unitrate,
reading,
connectiontype
```

From these 2 tables I require the data accoding to billno and meter no result is of the form

```
meterno,
billno,
cusstid,
connectiontype,
previousreading,
currentreading,
name,
amount
```

Answer (score 2):

The following gets the data you're looking for:

```
select b.meterno, b.billno, c.custid, c.connectiontype, b.previousreading, b.currentreading, c.fathername, b.amount
from bills b
  inner join customer c on c.meterno = b.meterno
```